# Android Studio and listener adapters

Tags: java, android-studio, adapter

I am new to android studio and app developing and I have a question:

I used to develop GUI (Eclipse, SWT) in java and I had to use listeners a lot. Listeners have multiple methods that must be implemented except if I use the adapter. The Adapter-logic allows me to implement only the methods that I need, not all of them.

I tried to find out if this logic applies in android studio too, but without success.

For example, I dont want to use the methods ***beforeTextChanged()*** and ***afterTextChanged()***:

private void checkDistanceInput() {

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance_input);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged() {
        // unimplemented
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged() {
        setDistanceTextChanged(editText);
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged() {
        // unimplemented
    }
});
```

}

Is there any chance to get rid of those two unimplemented methods?

Comment: Could you clear your concern ?? What you want and  what you tried. Codes will helpful in this case.

Comment: You are right. Post edited.

Comment: could you mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just make your own "Adapter" implementation for TextWatcher:
(btw. you forgot all the parameters of the methods)

```
public static abstract class TextWatcherAdapter implements TextWatcher {
    // Implament all 3 methods here, but leave their bodies empty
    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```

and now you have your "Adapter" (You can also set it to be abstract to ensure that something will be implemented)